# How to run assembly code without creating a new process?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, native-code

The file contains the native assembly code, and I want to run it in the current process.
But I don't want to create a real file (.com or .exe), so I tried:

```
...
using namespace std;
typedef void bitcode();
void testcode(){
    cout<<"test";
};
int main()
{
    bitcode *c=&testcode; // bitcode *c stands for the file containing the assembly code.
    bitcode *d=reinterpret_cast<bitcode*> (malloc(20));
    memcpy(d, c, 20);
    d(); // it doesn't work
    return 0;
};
```

However, it doesn't work when I invoke d();. I want to know what's the correct way to do this with C/C++.

(I'm on Windows, and I’d appreciate it very much if you could tell me how to make it on Linux)

Thanks a lot!

*PS: I'm **NOT** asking "Running a executable in **another** process without creating a new process."*

Comment: have a look at these :: http://mspgcc.sourceforge.net/manual/c1308.html  
http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/c-prog-mixing.html

Comment: It seems that the inline assembly should be placed in the C/CPP source file and be compiled into the .com or .exe, but I want to run the assembly code in files when the process is running.

Comment: When you say "native assembly code", do you mean assembly instructions like `xchg eax, eax`, or assembled machine code like `0x90`?

Comment: The latter, assembled machine code like `0x90`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on windows, this is code I wrote before. It works on Win7+VS2010 at least in my machine.

the base idea is that call VirtualAlloc to allocate memory with PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE flag.
And call it in right way, that is, keep the stack balance.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"


int emitcode[] = 
{0x83ec8b55,0x565340ec,0x0c758b57,0x8b087d8b,
 0x348d104d,0xcf3c8dce,0x6f0fd9f7,0x6f0fce04,
 0x0f08ce4c,0x10ce546f,0xce5c6f0f,0x646f0f18,
 0x6f0f20ce,0x0f28ce6c,0x30ce746f,0xce7c6f0f,
 0x04e70f38,0x4ce70fcf,0xe70f08cf,0x0f10cf54,
 0x18cf5ce7,0xcf64e70f,0x6ce70f20,0xe70f28cf,
 0x0f30cf74,0x38cf7ce7,0x7508c183,0xf8ae0fad,
 0x5e5f770f,0x5de58b5b,0xccccccc3};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int *src = new int[64];
    int *dst = new int[64];
    int *dst2 = new int[64];

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i){
        src[i] = i;
    }

    //fastercopy(dst,src, 64/2);

    void* address = NULL;
    address= VirtualAlloc(NULL,
            sizeof(emitcode),
            MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,
            PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    memcpy(address,emitcode,sizeof(emitcode));

    //call emit code from assemble
    __asm {
      push        20h  
      mov         eax,dword ptr [src]  
      push        eax  
      mov         ecx,dword ptr [dst]  
      push        ecx
      mov         ecx, dword ptr [address]
      call        ecx
      add         esp,0Ch 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i){
        printf("%d ",dst[i]);
    }

    //call emit code from function pointer
    typedef void (*FASTCALL)(void* dst, void* src, int len);
    FASTCALL fastcall;
    fastcall = (FASTCALL)address;
    fastcall(dst2,src,64/2);

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i){
        printf("%d ",dst2[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how to do the same but with assembly instruction code? for example emitcode is a text: move ax, add bx, ..ect

Answer (score 5):

Ignacio has described the general outline of how to do it.

Since you are on Windows, the function you need for this is [`VirtualAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `malloc`, notably with the [`PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag to obtain permissions to write the memory, and execute it.

Then, according to the documentation you *still* need to explicitly set the execution flag using [`VirtualProtect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after writing to the memory, and before executing it.

Finally, after using the memory you need to free it using [`VirtualFree`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `free`.

```
std::size_t size = 20;
void* mem = VirtualAlloc(nullptr, size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
// Write assembly opcodes to mem

DWORD old_protect;
VirtualProtect(mem, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &old_protect);
typedef (void)(*fptr)();
fptr f = *reinterpret_cast<fptr*>(&mem);

f();

// Later …
VirtualFree(mem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
```

Note the added indirection in the `reinterpret_cast`. This is necessary to avoid undefined behaviour: C++ does not allow casting between an object pointer and a function pointer. However, the above code is implementation-defined and thus OK as far as C++ is concerned.

Furthermore, note that I omitted the error-checking code in the above to keep it simple. You *must not do this* in real code. Refer to the documentation for information about correct error handling.

On Linux the workflow is analogous, just using different names for the functions.

Comment: @linzuzeng See the update. Apparently `VirtualProtect` is needed, even though the permission is the same. Furthermore, make sure that the size you allocate and protect is actually large enough for the whole assembly code that you want to execute, otherwise the execution will simply try to resume outside the protected region. Also note the other changes to my code – I should have read the documentation more carefully.

Comment: @harold Yes, that’s the problem: apparently it sometimes works even with wrong parameters. For instance, the last parameter of `VirtualProtect` **must not be null**. Nevertheless, I know code (not mine) that uses null as its last value, and has so for years, without any problems.

Answer (score 4):

You need to map a writable page, write your code to it, switch the page to executable, and then execute it.

Comment: Do you mean that I should try to avoid the DEP? Can you tell me how to do this in detail? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do note that there *are* [wrong ways](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/selinux-mem.html) of doing it though...

Answer (score 2):

..and since you also asked about linux

here, you can use `mmap`. 
~for example:

**foo.cpp**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <assert.h>

void bar(int n) { printf("bar invoked: %d\n", n); }
typedef void(*fp_bar)(int);

typedef union
{
   unsigned char*   pb;
   void*            pv;
   void(*pf)();
} 
foocodes;

//some _unencrypted random foo code segment
const unsigned char ar_foos[]=
{
    0xbb,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,   //mov ebx addy of a function to invoke
    0xb8,0x0d,0x00,0x00,0x00,   //mov eax 13 ~int input arg 
    0x50,                       //push eax
    0xff,0xd3,                  //call absolute addy ebx
    0x5b,                       //pop
    0x90,                       //throw in a nop to make up 16 foos
    0xC3                        //return
};


int main()
{
    size_t foos_size=sizeof ar_foos;
    foocodes ufoos;
    fp_bar pbar=&bar;
    assert(4==sizeof pbar); //example requires a 32bit fn address

    ufoos.pv=mmap(
        NULL, 
        foos_size, 
        PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, 
        MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,
        -1, 
        0);

    memcpy(ufoos.pv, ar_foos, foos_size);    
    memcpy(ufoos.pb+1, &pbar, sizeof pbar); //poke in the bar fn address

    ufoos.pf(); //invoke foo codes

    return munmap(ufoos.pv, foos_size);    
}
```

& here's commandline stuff:

```
$ uname -a
Linux violet-313 3.0.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 19 19:05:57 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
...

$ gcc -ofoo foo.cpp
$ ./foo
bar invoked: 13
```

(;ook, i also omitted error handling in the interests of clarity;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but are you looking for __asm keyword

More at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa297214(v=vs.60).aspx